# How to make 2d sprite move in a smooth wide arc in the direction of keypress?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I'm working on a small experimental project in Unity. I have a 2d sprite that moves forward with a velocity but I want it to turn left or right in a wide arc and keep moving in that direction on keypress.

1. I've tried to tweak its angular velocity to get the desired affect. Looks unnatural and it won't stop rotating.
2. Tried Lerping. Looks unnatural as well.

Code Snippet 1:

```
bool forward = true;
Vector3 movement;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (forward)
    {
        //Moves forward
        movement = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f);
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;
    }


    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        forward = false;
        movement = new Vector3(-0.05f, 0.05f, 0.0f);
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;
        rb.angularVelocity = 30;
    }

    if (transform.rotation.z == 90)
    {
        movement = new Vector3(-0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;
        rb.angularVelocity = 0;
    }

}
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
    Vector3 target = transform.position + new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0);  
    transform.position 
    =Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,target,Time.deltaTime);
    transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 
    new Vector3(0, 0, 90), Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what is the actual correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what youre trying to accomplish but here's some pseudo code of what I came up with to get you started...

Essentially, when a direction is pressed, you want to increase the velocity in that direction until all of the velocity is pointed that way. At the same time you want to decrease the velocity in the direction you were previously going until it is zero.

This is a simplified formula however - if you truly wanted the velocity to be constant throughout the entirety of the arc you would have to use some geometry, knowing that V=(velX^2 + velY^2)^.5 but this would get you pretty close...

```
float yvel = 1f, xvel;
float t;

void Update()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(xvel, yvel);

    t += Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        t = 0;
        StartCoroutine(Move());
    }
}

private IEnumerator Move()
{
    while (t < 2) // at time t, yvel will be zero and xvel will be 1
    {
        yvel = 1 - .5f * t; // decrease velocity in old direction
        xvel = .5f * t; // increase velocity in new direction
        yield return null;
    }
}
```